# Asp.net Carousel with different player types

Tags: c#, asp.net, carousel, mp4, flv

I have a webpage where I want to show a carousel of videos, the issue is that I use 2 diferent types of players, one for MP4 format and the other one for FLV.

I use an `if` condition in order to filter by the video format, depending on this I show a player or another one but the results are not what I expected because it is always showing the same player and not both of them.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="video-content">

<%

ItemRelaDoc[] video = this.RelaDocs["Vide"];

foreach ( var item in video)
{
    string[] fileParts = item.XItem["File"].Split('.');

    if (fileParts[1].Contains("mp4") || fileParts[1].Contains("MP4"))
    {
        %>    
            <video id="Mp4Video" class="video-content" poster="<%#Metadata.Instance.GetFileVirtualPath(((ItemRelaDoc)Container.DataItem).XItem["Thumb"])%>" controls>
            <source src= "<%# Metadata.Instance.GetFileVirtualPath(((ItemRelaDoc)Container.DataItem).XItem["File"]) %>" type="video/mp4">
        <% 
    }

    else 
    { 
        %>
            <div id="frameVideo<%# Container.ItemIndex %>"></div> 
            </div>
        <%
    } 

    %> //why this here?

    <% //again... why this here?         

}//END for-each loop

%>

</div>
```

Regards

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please write your question in English, since [Stack Overflow is an English site.](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676)

Comment: Done ! ty for your help

Comment: Your `else` doesn't do anything about playing FLV video... For MP4 you've used video tag (even provided a `src`), so the browser will show it's own controls.  For FLV video no browser paid licensing so you must create your own player in Flash (using AS3 code) or find free one. Flash output files are in SWF format, so use `<embed>` tag. See tutorial : [**SWF embed**](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_embed).

Comment: Thank you for your answers ! And is there any easier way to play flv and mp4 videos with the same player?